# Communicating between two computers on differnet networks using socket module

Tags: python, sockets

I was messing around with python sockets, and one of the things I tried which of course failed, was setting my IP to a random valid address, which gave me the "cannot assign address" error. How could I do this? right now the only server/client I can do is across the localhost, how would I have two computers on different networks connect through the socket module?

Comment: At least one of the two computers would need to be connected directly to the Internet with a globally routable IP address; then the other computer could connect to that IP address.  However, since most modern Internet setups use a dedicated Internet gateway device to shield the computers on its network from attacks, the typical work-around is to configure port-forwarding on the gateway device, and then have the connecting computer connect to the gateway's WAN IP address on the port that was specified to be forwarded to the target computer.

Comment: Your computer has to already have an IP address. It's not something your program can set up